# How to search with grep exactly string in a file via shell linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a file, the content of file has a string like this:

> '/ad/e','@'.base64_decode("ZXZhbA==").'($zad)', 'add'

I want to check the file has this string. But when I use grep to check, It always return false. I try some ways:

```
grep "'/ad/e','@'.base64_decode("ZXZhbA==").'($zad)', 'add'" foo.txt

grep "'/ad/e','@'\.base64_decode\("ZXZhbA\=\="\)\.'\(\$zad\)', 'add'" foo.txt

str="'/ad/e','@'\.base64_decode\("ZXZhbA\=\="\)\.'\(\$zad\)', 'add'"

grep "$str" foo.txt
```

Can you help me? Maybe, another command line.

This is my case:

```
while read str; do
    if [ ! -z "$str" ]; then
        if grep -Fxq "$str" "$file_path"; then
            do somthing
        fi
    fi
done < <(cat /usr/local/caotoc/db.dat)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: `grep -Fxq "$str"` is not safe because it will fail, or possibly do something strange, if `$str` begins with a hyphen, causing it to be handled as an option to `grep`.  `grep -Fxq -- "$str"` is safe.

Comment: `< <(cat /usr/local/caotoc/db.dat)` is a [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) (UUOC).  `< /usr/local/caotoc/db.dat` is simpler, faster, and probably more reliable.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to make sure the string is quoted properly. This is a bit of an art form, since your string contains both single and double quotes. 
One thought would be to use `read` and a here-document to avoid having to escape anything.

Second, you need to use `-F` to perform exact string matching instead of more general regular-expression matching.

```
IFS= read -r str <<'EOF'
'/ad/e','@'.base64_decode("ZXZhbA==").'($zad)', 'add'
EOF

grep -F "$str" foo.txt
```

---

Based on the update, you can use a simple loop to read them one at a time.

```
while IFS= read -r str; do
  grep -F "$str" foo.txt
done < /usr/local/caotoc/db.dat
```

You may be able to simply use the `-f` option to `grep`, which will cause `grep` to output lines from `foo.txt` that match *any* line from `db.dat`.

```
grep -f /usr/local/caotoc/db.dat -F foo.txt
```

Comment: I'm using `read` as a glorified assignment statement for a single string; I'm not iterating over a multi-line file.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to workaround regexes, the simplest way is to turn off regular expressions using `-F` (or `--fixed-strings`) option, which makes `grep` act like a simple string search

> -F, --fixed-strings       PATTERN is a set of newline-separated strings

like this:

```
grep -F "'/ad/e','@'.base64_decode(\"ZXZhbA==\").'(\$zad)', 'add'" test
```

Note: because of the shell, you still need to escape:

- double quotes
- dollar sign or else `$zad` is evaluated as an environment variable